# How do I append text after an answer in Octave?

Tags: octave

I am new to Octave and I've written the following function to combine sound pressure levels.  I want to present the answer with a reference value after it.  e.g.: ***83 dB re: 20µPa*** rather than just ***83***, but I don't know how to add the text after the answer.

```
function L_total = combineLevels(Lp) 
x = Lp./10; 
y = 10.^x; z = sum(y); 
L_total = 10*log10(z);
endfunction
```

Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Look into examples for `disp` and `fprintf`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use `fprintf` or `sprintf`. These functions allow you to construct strings that interpolate values from variables. Try:

```matlab
fprintf('%d dB re: %duPa\n', L_total, Lp);
```